# How to train an image similarity model on 20 millions images(total size 10GB)?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

My system is configured with 16GB RAM. I have tried to train image similarity model on 20 millions images(total size 10GB) using VGG19 and KNN's nearest neighbor. When tried to read images i am getting Memory error. Even I have tried to train model on 200000(total size 770MB) but issue is same. How I can read millions of images to train ML models.

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS,Core™ i7,Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2), 64-bit, 16GB RAM

```
import os
import skimage.io
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import offsetbox
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
from sklearn import manifold
import pickle
skimage.io.use_plugin('matplotlib')

dirPath = 'train_data'
args = [os.path.join(dirPath, filename) for filename in os.listdir(dirPath)]

imgs_train = [skimage.io.imread(arg, as_gray=False) for arg in args]
shape_img = (130, 130, 3)

model = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,
                                        input_shape=shape_img)
model.summary()
shape_img_resize = tuple([int(x) for x in model.input.shape[1:]])
input_shape_model = tuple([int(x) for x in model.input.shape[1:]])
output_shape_model = tuple([int(x) for x in model.output.shape[1:]])
n_epochs = None

def resize_img(img, shape_resized):
    img_resized = resize(img, shape_resized,
                         anti_aliasing=True,
                         preserve_range=True)
    assert img_resized.shape == shape_resized
    return img_resized

def normalize_img(img):
    return img / 255.

def transform_img(img, shape_resize):
    img_transformed = resize_img(img, shape_resize)
    img_transformed = normalize_img(img_transformed)
    return img_transformed

def apply_transformer(imgs, shape_resize):
    imgs_transform = [transform_img(img, shape_resize) for img in imgs]
    return imgs_transform

imgs_train_transformed = apply_transformer(imgs_train, shape_img_resize)
X_train = np.array(imgs_train_transformed).reshape((-1,) + input_shape_model)
E_train = model.predict(X_train)
E_train_flatten = E_train.reshape((-1, np.prod(output_shape_model)))
knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5, metric="cosine")
knn.fit(E_train_flatten)
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that keras is working well with generator, you should consider using one:
[python generator tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/generator),
[using a generator with keras (example)](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)

It allows you to load your image during your training, batch by batch.